# Angular Chart.js Multiple Canvas

Tags: angular, canvas, chart.js, ngfor

Below code can be used for only Chart, but I have to make multiple chart. How can I make the below code to be array of chart and show throught them using *ngFor in Canvas.

```js
@ViewChild('pr_chart') chartElementRef: ElementRef;
```

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  let ctx = this.chartElementRef.nativeElement;
  ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');

  this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
      }
    },
    data: {
      labels: [1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 1999, 2050],
      datasets: [{
        data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000],
        // label: "Africa",
        borderColor: '#3bd19c',
        fill: false
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas #pr_chart></canvas>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild` to get the list of matching references instead of just a single one?

Comment: I am not familiar with that, could you plase share me any example on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `@ViewChildren` to get multiple references of `<canvas #pr_chart></canvas>` instances. I put together an example showing how to do this using your example from above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-multiple-charts.

Essentially I have an array of chart elements on my controller:

```js
chartData: Chart.ChartData[] = [
  {
    labels: ['1500', '1600', '1700', '1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000],
      borderColor: 'red',
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  {
    labels: ['1500', '1600', '1700', '1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000].reverse(),
      borderColor: 'blue',
      fill: false
    }]
  }
];
```

These are used to render multiple charts in my template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of chartData" class="chart">
  <canvas #pr_chart></canvas>
</div>
```

Instead of just grabbing a single reference using `@ViewChild`, you can grab each of the `pr_chart` instances using `@ViewChildren`:

```js
@ViewChildren('pr_chart', { read: ElementRef }) chartElementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Once we have those references, we can loop through them to create the appropriate chart by using that reference along with the associated data:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.charts = this.chartElementRefs.map((chartElementRef, index) => {
    const config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, { data: this.chartData[index] });

    return new Chart(chartElementRef.nativeElement, config);
  });
}
```

Since in my example I was going to be duplicating most of the configuration for each of the charts and only the data was changing, I created a base configuration that was shared for each of the charts when rendering it:

```js
const baseConfig: Chart.ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ display: false }],
      yAxes: [{ display: false }],
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Multiple charts works fine when it's a static data, but the Charts data are added dynamically no charts shown